# Como pegar o próximo item do banco de dados

Tags: php, html5, slide

Eu estou tento um grande problema algum tempo, onde eu tento pegar o próximo item de um array, vindo de um BD, porém ele não funciona. O objetivo é para passar um slide com as imagens diferentes de usuários cadastrados em um BD.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section-heading center-holder">
        <h2>Alguns de nossos clientes</h2>
        <div class="section-heading-line"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br>tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-60">
        <ul class="slider">
            <?php
                $control_active = 2;
                $cont = 1;

                $users = "SELECT id_usuario, slug, nome, foto, email, views, table_status 
                FROM usuarios 
                WHERE table_status = 1 
                AND foto <> '' 
                AND views > 500
                AND slug NOT IN ('sergiomm')
                AND slug NOT LIKE '%dieta%'";

                $conn       = new conexao();
                $consulta   = $conn->consulta($users);
                $result     = $conn->busca($consulta);
                $total      = $conn->conta($consulta);

                if ($total > 3){
                while ($row = $conn->busca($consulta)){                                         

                    $linkInicial    = 'http://linkto.bio/';
                    $linkFinal      = str_replace('|:|', '', $row['foto']);
                    $linkCompleto   = $linkInicial . $linkFinal;
                    if($control_active == 2){               
                ?>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="slide<? echo $cont; ?>" name="slide" checked>
                <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>
                <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>
                <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>
                <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>
                <label for="slide<? echo $cont; ?>"></label> 
            </li>
            <?php 
                $control_active = 1; 
                    }else{                      
            ?>

            <? } $cont += 1; } } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<!-- /Nossos usuários -->
```

Eu queria que na linha `<img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>` pegasse as imagens posteriores.

Alguém pode me ajudar como resolver isso.

Comment: Para cada linha você deseja pegar todas as linhas posteriores?

Comment: Sim, a primeira beleza, ela faz certo, pega o primeiro item, mas as outras 3 linhas repetem o mesmo dado.

Comment: Eu tentei com next(), e com for também.

Comment: Primeiro, a imagem está salva em algum diretório do servidor? Segundo o campo existe no banco de dados? Poderia postar o código de PHP completo?

Comment: Sim, Nicolas. A imagem existe e com isso o campo também.

Comment: @NicolasPereira Editei com o código completo.

Comment: @MoisesFausto a sia cpmsiçta eça esta funcionando ? Está retornando algo ja pro $row? Não compreendi sua pergunta

Comment: Sim @NicolasPereira, ele retorna os dados do SELECT, eu trato esse dado e pego a imagem, passando do $row['foto'] para a variável.

Isso funciona "perfeitamente" para o primeiro item, mas eu quero saber como eu faço para pegar o próxima imagem (que existe!), para o próximo item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse ponto

```
<?for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){ ?>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide<? echo $cont; ?>" name="slide" checked>
```

você está gerando uma LI 4 vezes, de acordo com seu FOR. E em cada LI gerada você faz outro LOOP

```
<?php   
    while ($row = $conn->busca($consulta)){                                         
          $linkInicial  = 'http://linkto.bio/';
          $linkFinal        = str_replace('|:|', '', $row['foto']);
          $linkCompleto = $linkInicial . $linkFinal;
?>

    <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="Imagem da usuário <? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>

<? } ?>
```

Dessa forma, na primeira iteração do FOR, quando você chega no WHILE ele gera LINKS para todas as imagens recuperadas do banco. Na segunda iteração do FOR ele já não tem mais imagens para gerar, pois foram todas geradas antes.

Se o que você quer é gerar 4 LIs com todas as imagens existentes no banco, primeiro faça o WHILE guardando todos os links e slugs em arrays, com um índice controlado

```
<?
    $indice = 0;
    while ($row = $conn->busca($consulta)){                                         
        $linkInicial  = 'http://linkto.bio/';
        $linkFinal        = str_replace('|:|', '', $row['foto']);
        $linkCompleto[$indice] = $linkInicial . $linkFinal;
        $slug[$indice] = $row['slug'];
        $indice++;
    }
?>
```

depois faça o seu FOR para montar as LIs com todas as imagens

```
<? for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){ ?>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide<? echo $i; ?>" name="slide" checked>

        <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto[$i]; ?>" alt="Imagem da usuário <? echo $slug[$i]; ?>"/>

        <? } ?>

        <label for="slide<? echo $cont; ?>"></label>
    </li>

<? } ?>
```

Observações
Não é necessário um contador dentro do FOR, você pode usar o próprio $i para controlar.
Normalmente, arrays começam com o índice 0, por isso mudei o FOR para ser de 0 até 3 (4 posições)
Sempre é mais fácil controlar as coisas em arrays no PHP. Loops dentro de loops deixam mais complicado.

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Meu amigo, vc salvou o dia. Muito obrigado por ter me dado esse help!

Answer (score 0):

Quando vc faz
$linkCompleto   = $linkInicial . $linkFinal;
dentro do while, ele monta essa variável e você exibe ela três vezes.
Se você exibir só uma linha
" alt=""/>
você vai exibir uma vez o valor correto. As outras duas linhas vão mostrar repetido.

Porém, se você quer mostrar os valores anteriores, você deveria usar um array, com algo como
$linkCompleto[indice]   = $linkInicial . $linkFinal;
Aí, na hora de exibir, você usaria
" alt=""/>
" alt=""/>
" alt=""/>

Nesse caso você só teria os 3 valores prontos após o loop while executar 3 vezes. Além disso, seu 
if($control_active == 2)
também pode atrapalhar sua lógica.

Comment: Oi Pablo, bom dia. Obrigado pela resposta, acabou que eu não consegui fazer dessa forma que vc disse, mas eu mudei minha abordei eu deu '"certo'", apareceu os dados subsequentes, mas agora eles não aparecem no próximo item da lista.

Comment: Eu postei o codigo acima, com a resolução

Comment: Moises, publiquei outra resposta, como resposta a sua solução. Acho que agora fui mais claro e entendi melhor seu problema

Answer (score 0):

```
            $users = "SELECT id_usuario, slug, nome, foto, email, views, table_status 
            FROM usuarios 
            WHERE table_status = 1 
            AND foto <> '' 
            AND views > 500
            AND slug NOT IN ('thiago_hd', 'sergiomm', 'consultacaixa2019', 'maisempregocv', 'clubeamostrasgratis', 'saudetotal', 'sniperafiliados')
            AND slug NOT LIKE '%dieta%' limit 5";

            $conn       = new conexao();
            $consulta   = $conn->consulta($users);
            $result     = $conn->busca($consulta);
            $total      = $conn->conta($consulta);

            if ($total > 1){    
        ?>

        <? for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){ ?>

        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide<? echo $cont; ?>" name="slide" checked>

            <?php   
            while ($row = $conn->busca($consulta)){                                         
              $linkInicial  = 'http://linkto.bio/';
              $linkFinal        = str_replace('|:|', '', $row['foto']);
              $linkCompleto = $linkInicial . $linkFinal;
            ?>

                <img src="<? echo $linkCompleto; ?>" alt="Imagem da usuário <? echo $row['slug']; ?>"/>

            <? } ?>

            <label for="slide<? echo $cont; ?>"></label>
        </li>

        <?  $cont += 1; } ?>

        <? } ?>
    </ul>
```

RESULTADO -

```
    <ul class="slider">


        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide" checked>


                <img src="http://linkto.bio/arquivos/2018/09/vivian-telles.jpg" alt="Imagem da usuário viviantelles"/>


                <img src="http://linkto.bio/arquivos/2018/07/ecosafety.jpg" alt="Imagem da usuário botasecosafety"/>


                <img src="http://linkto.bio/arquivos/2018/06/sua-aventura.jpg" alt="Imagem da usuário suaaventura"/>


                <img src="http://linkto.bio/arquivos/2018/06/elba-ramalho.jpg" alt="Imagem da usuário locomotivelba"/>


            <label for="slide1"></label>
        </li>


        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide" checked>


            <label for="slide2"></label>
        </li>


        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide" checked>


            <label for="slide3"></label>
        </li>


                </ul>
```